# I am trying to parse through a json could some one help me

Tags: android, json, api

I excuted the followinf api request 
https://api-v3.mbta.com/predictions?sort=arrival_time&filter%5Bstop%5D=70028%2C70029
and I am having the following parsing problem.

```
  Failed to parse JSON
    org.json.JSONException: Value [{"attributes":{"arrival_time":"2018-04-25T13:20:01-04:00","departure_time":"2018-04-25T13:20:01-04:00",
"direction_id":1,"schedule_relationship":null,"status":null,"stop_sequence":140,"track":null}
,"id":"prediction-36315805-70029-140","relationships":{"route":{"data":{"id":"Orange","type":"route"}},"stop":
{"data":{"id":"70029","type":"stop"}},"trip":{"data":{"id":"36315805","type":"trip"}}},"type":"prediction"},{"attributes"
:{"arrival_time":"2018-04-25T13:26:03-04:00","departure_time":"2018-04-25T13:26:03-04:00","direction_id":0,"schedule_relationship":null,
"status":null,"stop_sequence":50,"track":null},"id":"prediction-36315802-70028-50","relationships":{"route":{"data":{"id":"Orange","type":"route"}},"stop":{"data":{"id":"70028","type":"stop"}},"trip":{"data":{"id":"36315802","type":"trip"}}},"type":"prediction"},{"attributes":{"arrival_time":"2018-04-25T13:29:28-04:00","departure_time":"2018-04-25T13:29:28-04:00","direction_id":1,"schedule_relationship":null,"status":null,"stop_sequence":140,"track":null},"id":"prediction-36315806-70029-140","relationships":{"route":{"data":{"id":"Orange","type":"route"}},"stop":{"data":{"id":"70029","type":"stop"}},"trip":{"data":{"id":"36315806","type":"trip"}}},"type":"prediction"},{"attributes":{"arrival_time":"2018-04-25T13:33:00-04:00","departure_time":"2018-04-25T13:33:00-04:00","direction_id":0,"schedule_relationship":null,"status":null,"stop_sequence":50,"track":null},"id":"prediction-36315803-70028-50","relationships":{"route":{"data":{"id":"Orange","type":"route"}},"stop":{"data":{"id":"70028","type":"stop"}},"trip":{"data":{"id":"36315803","type":"trip"}}},"type":"prediction"},{"attributes":{"arrival_time":"2018-04-25T13:36:20-04:00","departure_time":"2018-04-25T13:36:20-04:00","direction_id":1,"schedule_relationship":null,"status":null,"stop_sequence":140,"track":null},"id":"prediction-36315807-70029-140","relationships":{"route":{"data":{"id":"Orange","type":"route"}},"stop":{"data":{"id":"70029","type":"stop"}},"trip":{"data":{"id":"36315807","type":"trip"}}},"type":"prediction"},{"attributes":{"arrival_time":"2018-04-25T13:44:44-04:00","departure_time":"2018-04-25T13:44:44-04:00","direction_id":0,"schedule_relationship":"ADDED","status":null,"stop_sequence":50,"track":null},"id":"prediction-ADDED-1524238424-70028-50","relationships":{"route":{"data":{"id":"Orange","type":"route"}},"stop":{"data":{"id":"70028","type":"stop"}},"trip":{"data":{"id":"ADDED-1524238424","type":"trip"}}},"type":"prediction"},{"attributes":{"arrival_time":"2018-04-25T13:52:00-04:00","departure_time":"2018-04-25T13:52:00-04:00","direction_id":1,"schedule_relationship":null,"status":null,"stop_sequence":140,"track":null},"id":"prediction-36315809-70029-140","relationships":{"route":{"data":{"id":"Orange","type":"route"}},"stop":{"data":{"id":"70029","type":"stop"}},"trip":{"data":{"id":"36315809","type":"trip"}}},"type":"prediction"},{"attributes":{"arrival_time":"2018-04-25T13:52:39-04:00","departure_time":"2018-04-25T13:52:39-04:00","direction_id":0,"schedule_relationship":null,"status":null,"stop_sequence":50,"track":null},"id":"prediction-36315757-70028-50","relationships":{"route":{"data":{"id":"Orange","type":"route"}},"stop":{"data":{"id":"70028","type":"stop"}},"trip":{"data":{"id":"36315757","type":"trip"}}},"type":"prediction"},{"attributes":{"arrival_time":"2018-04-25T14:00:20-04:00","departure_time":"2018-04-25T14:00:20-04:00","direction_id":0,"schedule_relationship":null,"status":null,"stop_sequence":50,"track":null},"id":"prediction-36315758-70028-50","relationships":{"route":{"data":{"id":"Orange","type":"route"}},"stop":{"data":{"id":"70028","type":"stop"}},"trip":{"data":{"id":"36315758","type":"trip"}}},"type":"prediction"},{"attributes":{"arrival_time":"2018-04-25T14:09:34-04:00","departure_time":"2018-04-25T14:09:34-04:00","direction_id":1,"schedule_relationship":null,"status":null,"stop_sequence":140,"track":null},"id":"prediction-36315810-70029-140","relationships":{"route":{"data":{"id":"
```

I am parsing the code like  this

```
private void parseItems(List<GalleryItem> items, JSONObject jsonBody)
        throws IOException, JSONException {

    JSONObject photosJsonObject = jsonBody.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray photoJsonArray = photosJsonObject.getJSONArray("attributes");

    for (int i = 0; i < photoJsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject photoJsonObject = photoJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        GalleryItem item = new GalleryItem();
        item.setId(photoJsonObject.getString("arrival_time"));
        item.setCaption(photoJsonObject.getString("departure_time"));



        item.setUrl(photoJsonObject.getString("departure_time"));
        items.add(item);
    }
}
```

could some one tell me where  I am making a mistake when parsing the object.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from your posted json `data` is an array and `attributes` is an object, you were trying to parse them the other way around. Try this:

```
JSONArray data = jsonBody.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject singleData = data.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject attributes = singleData.getJSONObject("attributes");

    GalleryItem item = new GalleryItem();
    item.setId(attributes.getString("arrival_time"));
    item.setCaption(attributes.getString("departure_time"));



    item.setUrl(attributes.getString("departure_time"));
    items.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `data` is a JSONArray, and your `photosJsonObject` should be JSONArray not object, which contains the objects. Rest is ok I think.